# show variables is diferent in compare rds mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

using show variables command, in workbentch, I see that its different if I see parameter groups in RDS.

why ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AWS modifies the value as it applied it from the parameter group to the live MySQL instance. They have a lot of "plumbing" to support their automation of MySQL instances, but they reveal very little of how that works.

If you need greater control over your MySQL instance, then you should operate it yourself.

If you want the benefits of automation that AWS gives you with RDS, then you must give up some transparency of how it is operated.